# Second JFrame doesn't show from first JFrame

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe, multiple-instances

This is a simple `JFrame`application. It basically creates a new `Frame` on basis of the user choice. The first frame starts but the new one doesn't show up! It show the errors-
`ie1 cannot be resolved` & `ie2 cannot be resolved`. I want to see the new `Frame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Java test");
        Container c = jf.getContentPane();
        jf.setBounds(450, 180, 450, 450);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        c.add(jp);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("This is a text in a label",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jp.add(jl);
        JComboBox jcb1 = new JComboBox();
        jp.add(jcb1);
        jcb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent ie1) {
                ie1.getItem();
            }
        });
        jcb1.addItem("       Select the Size       ");
        jcb1.addItem("100 x 100");
        jcb1.addItem("200 x 200");
        jcb1.addItem("300 x 300");
        jcb1.addItem("400 x 400");
        jcb1.addItem("500 x 500");
        jcb1.addItem("600 x 600");
        JComboBox jcb2 = new JComboBox();
        jp.add(jcb2);
        jcb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent ie2) {
                ie2.getItem();
            }
        });
        jcb2.addItem("       Select the Colour     ");
        jcb2.addItem("Blue");
        jcb2.addItem("Red");
        jcb2.addItem("Black");
        jcb2.addItem("White");
        jcb2.addItem("Yellow");
        jcb2.addItem("Green");
        JButton jb = new JButton("Create a new Frame");
        jp.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                final JFrame jf1 = new JFrame("New Frame");
                Container c = jf1.getContentPane();
                jf1.setVisible(true);
                jf1.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // The Size of the frame
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("       Select the Size       ")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select the size of the Frame");
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("100 x 100"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 100, 100);
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("200 x 200"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 200, 200);
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("300 x 300"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 300, 300);
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("400 x 400"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 400, 400);
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("500 x 500"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 500, 500);
                }
                if (ie1.getItem().equals("600 x 600"))
                    ;
                {
                    jf1.setBounds(450, 180, 600, 600);
                }
                // The size of the Frame ends

                // The colour of the frame
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("       Select the Colour     ")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select the colour of the Frame");
                }
                final JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
                c.add(jp1);
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("Blue")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.blue);
                }
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("Red")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.red);
                }
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("Black")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.black);
                }
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("White")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("Yellow")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                }
                if (ie2.getItem().equals("Green")) {
                    jp1.setBackground(Color.green);
                }
                // the colour of the frame ends
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the lines that the errors refer to.

Comment: @zebediah49 The error refers to all lines in that have ie1 or ie2 in them except the itemEvent lines

Comment: You should try to format the code in your post. There is a missing `}` in your block code, and the indentation is not perfect. By the way, being 14 doesn't change anything here! Post good question and you'll have good answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are not instantiating, nor initializing the `ie1` and `ie2` variables anywhere. I can see these represent `ItemEvent` references, but their scope is limited to the `ItemListener` 'changed' method.

If you are using Eclipse, it should provide you with a quick fix. But if I were you, I would start reading on `Java for Beginners` first, and after that move onto the AWT/Swing and SWT/JFace stuff.

Try starting with more basic stuff. It occurs to me that the code above is a bit overwhelming for you. Good luck lil programmer.

Comment: but i have declared them as final. if this is the wrong way please tell me the right one. Thanks!

Comment: @Chinmay Dabke No no no. You have declared them as final INSIDE item event listeners. These go out of scope when you try to use them outside the listeners. Your code is flawed.

Comment: So how do i declare them so that they could be used anywhere?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Several things:
You don't need ItemListeners to get the selected value of the combo boxes, instead just do

```
Object ie1 = jcb1.getSelectedItem();
Object ie2 = jcb2.getSelectedItem();
```

right above

```
if(ie1.equals("       Select the Size       "))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select the size of the Frame");
}
```

And since you're using an anonymous inner class, you'll need to make sure `jcb1` and `jcb2` are declared `final`, like so:

```
final JComboBox jcb1 = new JComboBox();
```

Also, change `ie1.getItem().equals(...)` to just `ie1.equals(...)`, and do the same for `ie2`.

On another note, don't put semicolons after if statements.

Right:

```
if(ie1.equals("100 x 100")) 
{
    ...
}
```

Wrong:

```
if(ie1.equals("100 x 100"));
{                        //^
    ...
}
```

So remove the semicolons that you have after those if statements.

With all that said, I would definitely recommend going with GGrec's advice, and start reading some [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).